# NPSP - import contacts with roles (relationships)

Tags: npsp

In my legacy access file, I have one primary contact and I have another 10 contacts that are related to the primary as family members, friends or coworkers. How can I import everything from one CSV file into the NPSP

Comment: This is an advanced topic, it's supported via advanced mapping in NPSP data import tool. https://www.sforgdocs.com/npspdocs/en-gb/product_docs/ngo/npsp/ongoing_administration/advanced_mapping/map_using_advanced_mapping/topics/npsp-en-gb-map-using-advanced-mapping

Comment: The best resources for NPSP is the [NPSP Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sfdo.Nonprofit_Success_Pack.htm&type=5) and the [NPSP Trailblazer group](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F94S000000kHitSAE?tab=discussion&sort=LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_DESC).

Comment: Thank you, yes I was able to implement "Relationship Recipes" (https://www.sforgdocs.com/npspdocs/en-gb/product_docs/ngo/npsp/ongoing_administration/advanced_mapping/am_recipes/topics/npsp-en-gb-advanced-mapping-recipes#ariaid-title2)

But that is for contact 1 and 2 and I have contact 1 and contact 2-10